# hasClass is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a simple jquery code to animation an element on my page:

**curent**

```
 $('#tgs-nav-icon').on('click', function() {
    var $nav = (".canvas-menu-content");
    var bounceInRight = "bounceInRight animated";

    if(! $nav.hasClass(bounceInRight) ) {
        $nav.addClass(bounceInRight);
    }
    else {
        $nav.removeClass(bounceInRight);
    }

});
```

Uncaught TypeError: nav.hasclass is not a function

I tried testing this to see where I went wrong and this code comes back false as it should:

```
var help = $( ".canvas-menu-content" ); 
console.log(help.hasClass("foo"));
```

I can't figure out why the if statement is throwing me the error.

I've tried doing some research, but none of the previous questions seem to answer my issue.

Comment: You have a typo in that you neglected to put the `$` function name in front of what you intended to be its invocation parens (on line 2 of your code). As such I've voted to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning `$nav` to the string ".canvas-menu-content" here:

```
var $nav = (".canvas-menu-content");  // $nav is now '.canvas-menu-content'
```

Assign it to a jQuery object instead:

```
var $nav = $(".canvas-menu-content"); // $nav is now a jQuery object containing all 
                                      // elements with class canvas-menu-content
```

Comment: thank you. I'll mark this as correct when my time allows me to.